# PHP format('H:m') adds a minute

Tags: php

In my database, there's a field with "00:00:00" and a field with "15:00:00".

When I echo this in my php page with `format('H:m')` they show like "00:01" and "15:01". Without that format, they show like "00:00:00" and "15:00:00".

Does anyone know what could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m isn't minute, it is month. i is minute.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is January. Try `H:i` instead.